# Multiple power supplies in series: Negative voltage on one of them possible?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

It is common practice to connect multiple power supplies in series to obtain a higher voltage; examples: [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71296/connecting-switch-mode-power-supplies-in-series-to-increase-voltage?lq=1), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57030/connecting-power-supplies-in-series), [3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27832/putting-two-wall-warts-in-series), [4](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18350/can-two-atx-smps-be-connected-in-series-to-get-10-and-24v-dc). Many power supplies are designed to handle this application well. However, users are cautioned to check the manual of a power supply if it is really recommended to use it in series with another one.

One issue that might arise is called *polarity reversal*, i.e. a negative voltage being forced on the output of the "weakest" supply in the chain of series-connected devices. How is this possible?

Note: [Same story for batteries.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10654/negative-voltage-on-aa-battery) One should make sure that [the same type of battery is used together with another](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/60735/930), and that multiple series-connected batteries are in equally good (or mediocre) shape.

Answer (score 3):

The condition to consider for this to happen is a load beyond the rating of the supplies in question. Most severely, a short circuit. A short circuit need not be permanent and can even be a part of normal use: A motor, when starting, or a capacitor, when being charged from 0 V, looks like a short circuit, too.

To explain how a negative voltage can appear on one supply's output, let's use a diagram with some arrows. Supply A's output voltage shall be called V<sub>A</sub>, supply B's output V<sub>B</sub>, and the voltage across the load shall be called V<sub>L</sub>.

[image]
[Source](http://www.pulspower.com/pdf/cs10_481.pdf)

With KVL:

\$V_A + V_B = V_L\$

This is true for normal operation, when we want to use, for example, two supplies with V<sub>A</sub> = V<sub>B</sub> = 12 V for a load that needs V<sub>L</sub> = 24 V:

\$12V + 12V = 24V\$

For a short circuit, V<sub>L</sub> = 0 V, and KVL still applies. Thus, \$V_A + V_B = 0\$ or

\$V_A = -V_B\$

If we want to avoid negative voltages on any of the two supplies, the only possible solution is

\$V_A = V_B = 0\$

However, because of \$V = R \cdot I\$, and because any real power supply has a non-zero internal resistance, this also means that no current must flow. Now, a power supply will try to deliver current. Since the current or power limit of the two supplies will not be exactly equal, the "stronger" supply will be able to maintain a small, positive output voltage, and the only way to solve the KVL equation is by back-feeding the other supply, with a negative voltage across its output.